# Grails Quartz Plugin Freezes on the 8th execution

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

Environment: Grails 2.0.3, Quartz plugin 1.0-RC2

I have a simple quartz job that reads a value from the database. On the 8th execution, the Job freezes while reading from the database. There is also a web page that retrieves the value from the DB. Once the Job gets into the waiting state, attempting to read the value through the web page also freezes.

Answer (score 3):

Environment: Grails 2.2.0, Quartz plugin 1.0-RC5

I ran into the same problem using quartz-1.0-RC5.

As a workaround I replaced the `SessionBinderJobListener` class with the one from quartz-0.4.2 (changed only the package to the new one) and the job runs again without any problem. So it looks like the `persistenceInterceptor` bean does not close the connections or return them to the pool. Maybe there is a problem in `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor` with flush and destroy.

If `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` is much less than maxActive in `dataSource` properties, the problem does not appear (perhaps each job thread already got its connection) or it will only take longer.

Comment: Very clever Frank! I'll send this to the quartz team. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The default size of the datasource connection pool is 8, so you're probably not properly closing the connections to return them to the pool.

Comment: Downgrading to the 0.4.2 version of the plugin corrected the problem. Same code with the Job. I looked through the plugin documentation and didn't notice anything mentioning the need to explicitly close connections. I wonder if this is a bug in quartz 1.8.5, the version the 1.0-RC2 plugin uses.

Comment: I did notice this in the log: 07-23-2012 15:30:04 DEBUG org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache  >>caching query results in region: org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache; timestamp=5501251603378176
07-23-2012 15:30:04 DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager  >>transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same thing with Quartz plugin version 1.0.1. On the 8th execution both the Job and Tomcat workers freeze. Used  `withSession` and called Hibernate `session.disconnect()` in the `finally {}` block of the job. That did the trick.

```
def execute() {
   def hsession
   try {
     DomainObject.withSession { ses ->
       hsession = ses

       ....
     }
   } catch(Exception e) {
      //log it etc.
   } finally {
      hsession?.disconnect()
   }
}
```